# Composite Templates and EventNotifications

Tags: docusignapi

I am having issues with getting DocuSign connect to work correctly once an envelope using a template is completed. Here is my post body XML:

```
<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
<emailBlurb>Email blurb</emailBlurb>
<emailSubject>Inline Template Test</emailSubject>
<status>Sent</status>
<compositeTemplates>
    <compositeTemplate>
        <serverTemplates>
            <serverTemplate>
                <sequence>1</sequence>
                <templateId>TEMPLATE_ID</templateId>
            </serverTemplate>
        </serverTemplates>
        <inlineTemplates>
            <inlineTemplate>
                <sequence>2</sequence>
                <recipients>
                    <signers>
                        <signer>
                            <roleName>Developer</roleName>
                            <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                            <email>Signer Email</email>
                            <name>Signer Name</name>
                        </signer>
                    </signers>
                </recipients>
            </inlineTemplate>
        </inlineTemplates>
        <document>
            <name>tester2.tif</name>
            <documentId>1</documentId>
        </document>
    </compositeTemplate>
</compositeTemplates>
<eventNotification>
    <EnvelopeEvents>
        <envelopeEvent>
            <envelopeEventStatusCode>completed</envelopeEventStatusCode>
        </envelopeEvent>
    </EnvelopeEvents>
    <includeDocuments>true</includeDocuments>
    <loggingEnabled>true</loggingEnabled>
    <requireAcknowledgement>true</requireAcknowledgement>
    <url>CALLBACK_URL</url>
</eventNotification>
```

This eventNotification code works correctly with both regular sent and draft envelopes, just not composite templates.

Answer (score 2):

It seems to me that you've encountered a bug.  Although I've never personally used Event Notifications via API with Composite Templates, there's no obvious reason why it shouldn't work.  I'd suggest that you contact DocuSign Support to open a case with them -- you can point them to this thread here on StackOverflow for repro steps (see below).

**Scenario 1: Create Envelope using a Template, with Event Notification (works)**

Submitting the following request successfully creates/sends an Envelope:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>a872df3n-XXXX-XXXX-9b6a-6f4bf80e30fb</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
   <templateId>2C693B39-43E9-4101-B9D6-B62F2762F50C</templateId>
   <templateRoles>
      <templateRole>
         <email>johnsEmail@outlook.com</email>
         <name>John Doe</name>
         <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
      </templateRole>
   </templateRoles>
   <eventNotification>
    <EnvelopeEvents>
      <envelopeEvent>
        <envelopeEventStatusCode>completed</envelopeEventStatusCode>
      </envelopeEvent>
    </EnvelopeEvents>
    <includeDocuments>true</includeDocuments>
    <loggingEnabled>true</loggingEnabled>
    <requireAcknowledgement>true</requireAcknowledgement>
    <url>http://www.google.com</url>
   </eventNotification>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

When the Envelope is Completed, Connect fires an Event notification to the specified URL, as noted in the Connect Log:

[image: Connect Log Entry]

**Scenario 2: Create Envelope using Composite Templates, with Event Notification (does NOT work)**

Submitting the following request successfully creates/sends an Envelope:

```
POST https://{{env}}.docusign.net/restapi/{{version}}/accounts/{{acctId}}/envelopes

<envelopeDefinition xmlns="http://www.docusign.com/restapi">
   <accountId>a872df3n-XXXX-XXXX-9b6a-6f4bf80e30fb</accountId>
   <status>sent</status>
    <emailSubject>test Comp Templates with Event Notif</emailSubject>
    <compositeTemplates>
        <compositeTemplate>
            <serverTemplates>
                <serverTemplate>
                    <sequence>1</sequence>
                    <templateId>2C693B39-43E9-4101-B9D6-B62F2762F50C</templateId>
                </serverTemplate>
            </serverTemplates>
            <inlineTemplates>
                <inlineTemplate>
                    <sequence>2</sequence>
                    <recipients>
                            <signers>
                                <signer>
                                    <email>johnsEmail@outlook.com</email>
                                    <name>John Doe</name>
                                    <roleName>Signer1</roleName>
                                    <recipientId>1</recipientId>
                                </signer>
                            </signers>
                    </recipients>
                </inlineTemplate>
            </inlineTemplates>
        </compositeTemplate>
    </compositeTemplates>
    <eventNotification>
     <EnvelopeEvents>
       <envelopeEvent>
        <envelopeEventStatusCode>completed</envelopeEventStatusCode>
       </envelopeEvent>
     </EnvelopeEvents>
     <includeDocuments>true</includeDocuments>
     <loggingEnabled>true</loggingEnabled>
     <requireAcknowledgement>true</requireAcknowledgement>
     <url>http://www.google.com</url>
    </eventNotification>
</envelopeDefinition>
```

However, when the Envelope is Completed, Connect does NOT fire an Event notification to the specified URL -- i.e., the Connect Log never shows an entry for that Envelope.  I'd suspect that this is a bug, since I'm unable to locate any documentation that implies otherwise.

Comment: Thank you Kim, I tried calling the support number you listed but couldn't find a human, so i sent them an email referencing your detailed steps.

Comment: I got a response from support@docusign.com saying they don't support the API and to contact enterprisesupport, emailed them and no word yet. Will keep you posted